# ivy counsel find-file with similar name

Tags: find-file, ivy, counsel

In the directory I have `mongodb.js`, now I want to create a `db.js` file but if I type the name and press enter counsel-find-file use regex to open mongo**db.js**.

How can i create a `db.js` with counsel-find-file in the same directory of `mongodb.js`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> when you're at prompt line. Binds to `ivy-immediate-done`

As [manual](https://oremacs.com/swiper/#key-bindings-for-single-selection-action-then-exit-minibuffer) states it goes with current input instead the current candidate.